# Unable to edit a gridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Getting the exception object not set to an instance of an object.
Nothing gets saved to the grid view.
The run-time continues to display the object reference exception.
This is not a nullreferenceexception error.

```
    using (var context = new CAREntities1())
        {


         var args = sender as GridViewRowEditEndedEventArgs;
         CAR.ASSET localasset = args.EditedItem as CAR.ASSET;
         if (args.EditAction ==     
         Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewEditAction.Commit)

         if (args.EditOperationType == 
         Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewEditOperationType.Edit)

         var entity = context.ASSETS.Find(localasset.BARCODE);
                        if (entity == null)

                            return;



 context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(localasset);

                  context.SaveChanges();///saves to the database
```

Getting the error object not set to an instance of an object.  I am trying 
to edit a record within a Grid-view.

Comment: where do you get that error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The code sits within an event as soon as I edit the value and press enter the error happens.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with a NullreferenceException.